# The numbers $x, y, z$ and $w$ satisfies $x + 2y = 3z + w$ and $z + 2w = 3x + y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The numbers $x, y, z$ and $w$ satisfies $x + 2y = 3z + w$ and $z + 2w = 3x + y$.

Which of the following statements aren't necessarily true?

**A)** $y + w = 2(z + x )$

**B)** $x − 3z = w − 2y$

**C)** $4x + 3y = 4z + 3w$

**D)** $z + 2w = 3(3z + w − 2y) + y $

**E)** $z + 3x = y + 2w $

Comment: First thing I'd try: rearrange one of the equations for a variable, and substitute that into the other equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your System can be written in the form
$$x+2y=w+3z$$
$$3x+y=2w+z$$
adding both we obtain
$$4x+3y=3w+4z$$ this is option $C$
if we multiply the first equation by $-3$ and adding to the second we have
$$-5y+w+8z=0$$ and this is Option $D$
simplifying the equation $E$ we get $$3x-y-2w+z=0$$ and this is your second equation
simplifying $B$ we get your first equation
multiplying your first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$2x-y+2z-w=0$$ and this is Option $A$
and thus all is solved

Comment: It remains to show that option (E) does not follow from the hypotheses.  Using what you've written already, one could finish by looking at the [row reduction of the overall system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1,2,-3,-1%7D,%7B-3,-1,1,2%7D,%7B-2,1,-2,1%7D,%7B1,2,-3,-1%7D,%7B4,3,-4,-3%7D,%7B0,5,-8,-1%7D,%7B3,-1,1,-2%7D%7D) to conclude that there must be at least one of the equations that doesn't follow from the original two.